# Твоя работа, Петя, (—) наблюдать

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Будет ли здесь отсутствовать тире (по аналогии со случаем, когда между подлежащим и сказуемым находится вводное слово, частица и т. д.)?

*Твоя работа, Петя, (—) наблюдать.*

Answer (score 2):

Вот что пишет Д. Э. Розенталь ([§ 5. Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=91)).

**Тире** ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым при отсутствии связки, если оба главных члена предложения выражены с у щ е с т в и т е л ь н ы м и в форме именительного падежа.
**Примечание.** Обычно тире не ставится:
2) если в роли связки выступают *сравнительные союзы **как, будто, словно, точно, вроде как, всё равно что*** и т. п.
3) если перед сказуемым стоит *отрицание **не***;
4) если между подлежащим и сказуемым стоит *вводное слово,* иногда — *наречие, союз, частица*:  ***Март** т о л ь к о **начало** весны.*

Обращения он не упоминает.

Об обращении говорят специалисты [кафедры общего и русского языкознания НГУ](https://dict.nsu.ru/mod/book/view.php?id=12&chapterid=55) .

Между подлежащим и сказуемым, выраженными именами существительными, тире не ставится, если между ними имеются какие-либо члены или **компоненты** предложения.

*Самое главное, **бабуся, не** угощение, **а** взаимопонимание и товарищеская поддержка между передовыми людьми* [В. Ф. Панова. Ясный берег (1949)].
Подлежащее выражено субстантивированным прилагательным "главное", а сказуемое – рядом однородных членов "**не** угощение, **а** взаимопонимание и поддержка", соединенных противительным союзом ***не... а***.
Наличие обращения "бабуся" отменяет постановку тире.

Все эти особенности подходят только для тех случаев, когда и подлежащее, и сказуемое выражены существительными. Для нашего предложения они не годятся.

Розенталь:
Тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым, если оба они выражены неопределенной формой глагола (инфинитивом) или если один из главных членов выражен формой именительного падежа существительного, а другой — неопределенной формой глагола: *О решённом **говорить** — только **путать*** (М. Г.).
И никаких примечаний.

Филологи из НГУ еще категоричнее (см. пункт 2.3):
При таком способе выражения подлежащего и сказуемого тире ставится всегда и без исключений.

Сравните (со словом "только"):
***Март** только **начало** весны.* [без тире]
*О решённом **говорить** — только **путать.*** [с тире]

Так что, думаю, тире надо ставить. **Твоя работа, Петя, — наблюдать.**

Нашелся, правда, пример ([М. Горький. Мать](https://books.google.ee/books?id=AwucDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA121&lpg=PA121&dq=%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%E2%80%93%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE!%20%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE,%20%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB,%20%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE!&source=bl&ots=MjzcrF2fVj&sig=ACfU3U3276IPuOaDyhivTMLSDS6tKusfVg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjD5ZyQhJvqAhVopIsKHW25BrQQ6AEwAXoECAwQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%E2%80%93%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE!%20%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%2C%20%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE!&f=false)), где тире при наличии обращения отсутствует (я бы его поставила). Возможно, это авторская пунктуация.

> — А потом встанет нам на дороге! — тихо заметил Павел.
> — **Наше дело — не допустить этого! Наше дело, Павел, сдержать его!** Мы к нему всех ближе, — нам он поверит, за нами пойдет!

Comment: Римма, хорошая информация Вам попалась. Плюс!

Comment: Похоже, что эта информация интересна только Вам. Даже автор вопроса _никак_ не реагирует.